# Spell for making all vision black and white?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Is there a spell or similar effect that can make a room or chamber where all vision is only black and white?

Comment: How open is the GM to ... creative uses of crafting magic items, or to slight modifications to existing spells? Also, how absolute is "all" (if, eg., powerful outsiders or creatures with specific feats can still see in color, but most creatures are limited to B&W, is that acceptable)?

Comment: Close to existing is fine

Comment: May I ask why you need this? May affect the answers.

Comment: @ShadowKras I’m the GM creating an encounter. Mainly just for stunning visual effect. But because it’s part of a campaign with multiple GMs and a large player pool, we like to try and stick with stuff within the rules framework as opposed to just making up a bunch of homebrew stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for cool visual effects with no real impact in the game mechanics. Then the simplest answer is: **Illusions**.

Characters have no reason to suspect anything because its not doing any harm. They might use *Detect Magic* but you can say the truth, there is a weak illusion effect in the whole room. If they dispel it, they will see that there was nothing special about it. But this is exactly the kind of things within the scope of illusionists.

Another option would be the spells of **Curse Terrain**, from *Horror Adventures*, which create curses that affect an area instead if creatures. This is merely a spooky visual effect, with no impact on those walking inside, so you could say its a *minor curse*. Instead of illusions, those are necromancy effects.

Comment: To expand on this idea, since many creatures naturally perceive the world in monochrome, this GM would likely allow the spell [*hallucinatory terrain*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hallucinatory-terrain/) to have the effect the asker wants without the spell otherwise having an impact on the environment. However, my concern is that the creatures that enter the illusionary area still wouldn't perceive in monochrome *each other*, but, then again, the spell [*veil*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/veil/) can fix that.

Comment: Evocation would also fit, if you're changing the actual properties of the light rather than just making it look different.

Comment: I actually like the cursed terrain version. Unless FrancisJohn would like the party to throw out one or more Dispel Magics at a non-encounter.

Answer (score 3):

Darkvision only grants B&W sight, so one solution would be to create darkness by magical or nonmagical methods and then give everybody Goggles of Night or similar.

It would take a bit of tweaking to the darkness effects since neither Darkness nor Deeper Darkness can be used with Permanency, and they can become either not-dark-enough or super-dark depending on how much light there is for them to suppress.